# Can I determine part of filepath in formula based on value of a different cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I understand that excel is not the best tool for this project, but I have been told it is the tool I will use for this.

I have a workbook where one worksheet is compiling data from 4 other workbooks into a single table.  Every year we have to build a new set of workbooks, etc.

If cell E2 has the formula:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("BATCH #",'[2019 Q1 Data Sheet.xlsm]Q1W1'!$A$1),0)
```

and Cell E3 has the formula:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("BATCH #",'[2019 Q1 Data Sheet.xlsm]Q1W2'!$A$1),0)
```

Is it possible to rewrite these formulas so that the "Q#W#" portion of it is determined by the value in cell A12 and A3?

The way this project was set up resulted in there being more than 52 weeks in the year (yeah I know it's not the best design but it is what I was handed).

So I would like to have a formula where the Q#W# portion is dynamic, and the value in that part of the formula is located in a different cell so we can easily change the formulas every year as opposed to changing each cell one at a time.  I've tried a macro find and replace for some of this project but for this part I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: INDIRECT should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the worksheets with 
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)

Then use CONCAT to define the worksheet of interest (the reference to Q#W#) in the formula to pull the data from.